# some of json fields not being parsed by json object

Tags: android, tastypie

I am able to recieve the json response from a tastypie rest service. the problem i am having now is fetching individual values from the json object. here is the problem

```
a={"pincode":"7593836483048364830843","id":"5","resource_uri":"\/api\/oncredit\/prepaid\/5\/","amount_charged":"200","used":false,"network_type":"AIRTEL","user":"\/api\/oncredit\/user\/1\/"}

public void getJSONValue(String a){
    JSONSTRING = a;
    try { 
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSONSTRING);
        String pincode = obj.getString("pincode");
        String amount_charged = obj.getString("amount_charged"); 

    } catch (JSONException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

the problem i am facing now is when debuging, the value of pincode is set to null along with used, resource_url. I dont know why it is being set to null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
String pincode=(String)obj.get("pincode");
```

Comment: If the answer provided is helpful. Please click the green check mark on next to it,and mark it as answer, so others in the future knows that it was helpful as well.